# Handling exception std::out_of_range c++

Tags: c++, istream, formatted-input

I am trying to read flight schedules from a file into a `Flight` class.

I experienced a problemn when using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. I tried with same code on `tutorialspoint` c++ online compiler and all works fine.

Here is example data of the text file:

```
LAS VEGAS; 21:15; AA223; A3;
DALLAS; 21:00; BA036; A3;
LONDON; 20:30; AA220; B4;
MEXICO; 19:00; VI303; B4;
LONDON; 17:45; BA087; B4;
```

Here the error message I receive:

> Unhandled exception at 0x75F25B68 in sf.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x00C5EE9C.

And here the stream extractor in which the problem apparently occurs

```
istream &operator>>(istream &is, Flight &f) {
    std::string singleLine;
    is >> singleLine;
    std::string s0, s1, s2, s3;
    size_t loc = singleLine.find(';');
    s0 = singleLine.substr(0, loc);
    singleLine.erase(0, loc + 1);
    loc = singleLine.find(';');
    s1 = singleLine.substr(1, loc - 1);
    singleLine.erase(0, loc + 1);
    loc = singleLine.find(';');
    s2 = singleLine.substr(1, loc - 1);
    singleLine.erase(0, loc + 1);
    s3 = singleLine.substr(1, 2);


    f.set_lightNo(s0);
    f.set_destination(s1);
    f.set_departure(s2);
    f.set_gateNo(s3);
    return is;
}
```

Comment: "it does not want to compile my file" contradicts the runtime error: you can't run the program without having compiled it. Anyway, use the Visual Studio **debugger**. You can ask it to break on a *first chance exception*.

Comment: As a Stack Overflow question this needs a *complete but minimal example*. Voting to close.

Comment: FWIW, `std::string::find` can be called with a second argument that gives the position to start the search. So each search can start right after the delimiter, without needing to erase the preceding text..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you read the lines with:

```
is >> singleLine;  // <== ouch !
```

The `singleLine` will then end at the first whitespace encountered and not hold the full line !

In your example data, the first whitespace is immediately after the first `;`.  So when you do the second `find(';')`, the return value will be not found, i.e. [`string::npos`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/), which is the maximum that `loc` can contain ( avery very big number).  When you then try to access to `substr(1, loc - 1)` you're definitively out of range.

It should work if you replace the line with:

```
getline (is, singleLine); // will get the full line until nweline or eof
```

**Suggestion:**

A further improvement would be to check that the read was successful before  anything else:

```
istream &operator>>(istream &is, Flight &f) {
    std::string singleLine;
    if (getline (is, singleLine)) { 
        ...
    }
    return is;
}
```